# How do i open different information for each polygon i've created? Google maps api v3

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, polygon, infowindow

Here is the code i'm currently running:
The user is able to create their own polygon after their polygons are shown on the map i want to display some information about every polygon. I'm now opening an infowindow but i can't get information for different polygons

Any thoughts?

```
<?php foreach ($area->result() as $f):?>

// Create an array with the coordanates of each area

var area<?=$f->id?>Coords = [
    <?php $latlng=$this->resources_data->field_latlng($f->id);?>
    <?php foreach ($latlng->result() as $point):?>
    new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$point->lat?>, <?=$point->lng?>),
    <?php endforeach;?>
];

// Create a polygon with the points of the area

var area<?=$f->id?>=new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: area<?=$f->id?>Coords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
});
// Add the Field to the map.
area<?=$f->id?>.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(field<?=$f->id?>,'click',function(event){
      infowindow.setContent(contentString);
      if (event) {
         point = event.latLng;
      }
      infowindow.setPosition(point);
      infowindow.open(map);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });


<?php endforeach;?>

var contentString = '<div id="content" class="h300 rad3">'+
    '<div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h2 ><?=$f->name?> </h2>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<div class="bgC m20l glow3cb rad3 h100 w350 inlineB vtop m15b m15r">' +
    ' '+
    ''+
    '<div class="inlineT vtop w180 m5l"> '+
    '<div class="inlineT vtop m5l"> '+
    '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to associate the infoWindow contents with the polygon is to use function closure, as done in [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_clickable_squares.html) (see the createClickablePoly function).  If you don't need a clickable sidebar, you can simplify that function to:

```
function createClickablePoly(poly, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly,'click', function(event) {
      infowindow.setContent(contentString);
      infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
      infowindow.open(map);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I couldn't make it to work yet. I'm trying to understand do i need to add the script "scripts/v3_epoly.js" ? What i did is i replaced the function :
google.maps.event.addListener(field<?=$f->id?>,'click',function(event){
      infowindow.setContent(contentString);
      if (event) {
         point = event.latLng;
      }
      infowindow.setPosition(point);
      infowindow.open(map);
});
that was in my code by the one you suggested me. still not working. Is this the best path to do this? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you are going to use the version of the function from that page, you will need epoly; if you use the simplified version in my post, you don't. You do however need the function createClickablePoly or you won't get function closure.

Comment: Ok i've added createClickablePoly(field<?=$f->id?>, "<div>test</div>"); after that the infowindow oppened but just with "test" text i would like to open whatever is on contentString. The problem is that i don't have freedom under the infowindow I would like to add some php programing and some clickable buttons on infowindow is it possible ? Thanks

Comment: It is certainly possible. You just have to understand that PHP is running on the server, you need the call to the function to be done in the client with the correct arguments. Do a view source on your page and see what PHP is creating.

Comment: Just a last quick question is the infobox worth it for my situation ?

Comment: You asked "is the infobox worth it for my situation"? I can't say, I don't see any reason to use it over the built in infowindow unless you intend to customize it.

Comment: Thanks. Its already too complicated for me i'll try to be simpler do you know any library that talks about infowindows?