# Cannot get info bubble to pop up when clicking polygon

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The polygons display fine and I am not seeing any errors when I debug in chrome. The data points for the polygons is being queried in c# code but is not relevant to this issue. When I click the polygon the js code seems to fire but I get no info bubble. I will be adding information to the info bubble about the polygon next but need to start with getting it to pop up first. Any help would be appreciated!

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 5,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.2979536, -97.7470835),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
             });

    <%for(int i = 0; i < this.zips2.Count; ++i )%>
    <%{ %>
        <%if ( layerType == "Orders" )
        { 
            GetOrderColor(zips3[i]); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            GetAptColor(zips3[i]);  
        } %>

        var paths = [<%=zips2[i]%>];
            var color = "<%=color%>";

            var shape = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: paths,
            strokeColor: color,
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: color,
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            clickable: true
            });


            shape.setMap(map);


            google.maps.event.addListener(shape, 'rightclick', function(event) {

            var contentString = '<div id="content:">' + "Test" + '</div>';
             infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
             infowindow1.setContent(contentString);
             infowindow1.open(map, this);

            });


      <%} %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i open different information for each polygon i've created? Google maps api v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020757/how-do-i-open-different-information-for-each-polygon-ive-created-google-maps-a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to opening an infoWindow on a polygon is understanding that it is different from opening an infoWindow on a marker ([google.maps.InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)):

Your code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(shape, 'rightclick', function(event) {
   var contentString = '<div id="content:">' + "Test" + '</div>';
   infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   infowindow1.setContent(contentString);
   infowindow1.open(map, this);  // <--- what is "this"? 
});
```

what is "this" in your code? Is it an MVC object that exports position? A [google.maps.Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) doesn't.

My code from [that example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020757/how-do-i-open-different-information-for-each-polygon-ive-created-google-maps-a):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly,'click', function(event) {
  infowindow.setContent(contentString);
  infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
  infowindow.open(map);
});
```