# Trying to put count variable in action Listener in Google Maps v3 however always calls last count figure

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Good morning,

I have a piece of JS reading a XML file and creating a series of Polygons, I have then added an action listener to those polygons.

However as part of that function I want to have the count variable past to the function.

```
// Code to read XML file then loop through...

for (var i = 0; i < zones.length; i++)

// Create a "new" dbpolygon

dbpolygon = new google.maps.Polygon
({paths : polygonPoints});

// add to array

zonepolygons.push(dbpolygon);
zonepolygons[zonepolygons.length - 1].setMap(map);


var userclick =  new google.maps.event.addListener(dbpolygon, 'click',  function() 
{    
load_sample_results(field,i);
});
```

So I'm creating a new polygon eachtime and then adding an action listener to that newly created polygon object.  However the function always has the variable 'i' set to the last count of i and not the count at creation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i open different information for each polygon i've created? Google maps api v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020757/how-do-i-open-different-information-for-each-polygon-ive-created-google-maps-a)

Comment: Is this your actual code?  If so you're missing `{` `}` for your for-loop, so there's only one line executed within the loop, `dbpolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({paths : polygonPoints});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the [answer from Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/185283/2087904)

you have to sourround your .addEventListener() with a let or with statement.

Comment: Perfect, I used to solution from Shog9
for (var i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
   // variables introduced in this statement 
   // are scoped to the block following it.
   let (num = i) 
   {
      setTimeout(function() { alert(num); }, 10);
   }
}